# Python Rejects Valid JSON

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to process this JSON using python3:
http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDV60701/IDV60701.94857.json

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./weath.py", line 41, in <module>
    data1                   = response.json()
  File "/home/dz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/dz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/dz/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

https://jsonlint.com/

Validates the JSON as valid, so I'm not sure why this is failing.

Here is the python code:

```py
url                     = "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDV60701/IDV60701.94857.json"
response                = requests.get(url)
data1                   = response.json()
```

This was working 2 week ago.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Read the error again. It complains about an invisible `NUL` character at the start of the text. Unless you include that NUL in the text you copy to JSON lint you won't get any errors.

Comment: It seems to be somethings with website error: response.text
Output: 'Potential automated request detected! We are making changes to our website therefore web scraping is no longer supported. Please contact us by filling in the details at http://reg.bom.gov.au/screenscraper/screenscraper_enquiry_form/ and we will get in touch with you.'

Comment: Mike, typing the url into the browser worked and I had no reason to suspect the BOM were doing something as nasty as this. I shouldn't need to point out that my taxes fund this organisation.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue related to the specific service endpoint you're using. They have disabled web scraping through some mechanism.

If you look at your response object, you'll see it's a 403 (forbidden) with the following message:

> Potential automated request detected! We are making changes to our website therefore web scraping is no longer supported. Please contact us by filling in the details at http://reg.bom.gov.au/screenscraper/screenscraper_enquiry_form/ and we will get in touch with you.

You can verify this for yourself:

```
response = requests.get("http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDV60701/IDV60701.94857.json")
print(response.status_code)  # 403
print(response.text)  # above quote
```

Answer (score 1):

When I ran this code:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDV60701/IDV60701.94857.json"
response = requests.get(url).text

print(response)
```

The print returned

```
Potential automated request detected! We are making changes to our website therefore web scraping is no longer supported. Please contact us by filling in the details at http://reg.bom.gov.au/screenscraper/screenscraper_enquiry_form/ and we will get in touch with you.
```

Seems like that website has disabled web-scraping or something

Comment: try to add headers from browser. I think this should do the trick :)

Comment: I've contacted them.